# While exists in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

How should i use while loop in mysql?

```
while exists (select * from table1) 
Do
 //sql statements
end while
```

> Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  while....

This what I want to do:

1. Inserting 20K records into a table2 from table1.
2. Looping table1 and inserting to table 
   3 the first 50 records. Deleting table1's 50 records with joining table3.
3. End loop when 20K records are deleted from table1.

Any help/thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered if a set based approach would be possible instead?

Comment: @Mark - I am not sure how to use set based approach, all am trying is for some number of records i need to loop and insert into, am open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you iteratively deleting from table1?

EDIT: Also, is there a semicolon after your `END WHILE` ?

Comment: 1. Inserting 20K records into a table2 from table1.
2. Looping table1 and inserting to table 3 the first 50 records.
    Deleting table1's 50 records with joining table3.
3. End loop when 20K records are deleted from table1.

Comment: I tried with semicolon ->End while; and without semicolon End while but didn't make any difference.

Comment: so you want to insert 50 rows at a time into table3 until 20k rows are done?
I guess I don't understand this goal....

Comment: @Sharpeye500: It sounds like you can do it with `INSERT ... SELECT ...` instead of a loop, but it's hard to tell from your rather brief description. If you gave some details about the problem you are trying to solve (currently you describe only your attempted solution) then I think you would get better answers.

Comment: First 50 records based on what?  We need to know the columns of the table being copied *from*, and copied *to*.  And are there more than 20K records in the table being copied from?

Answer (score 3):

You might try making sure there is a semicolon after your `END WHILE`
Or alternatively try putting a `BEGIN` and `END;` around your statements.

However, we really should examine a set-based method.

EDIT: If, as in your comments, you are determined to do this in 50 row batches.... for whatever reason...
You may try selecting the rowcount, then dividing it by your batch size to get an interation count variable.

For example, if you have 20,000 rows and you are inserting them in batched of 50 then you know that you will need 400 iterations. Then you can use an int and do `WHILE X < 400`
This will be faster than doing `EXISTS` queries.

Untested code (probably not valid syntax either, but should give you the idea)

```
INSERT INTO table2 (columns)
SELECT columns from table1

DECLARE @TopCount int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE @CurrCount int DEFAULT 0;
SELECT @TopCount = COUNT(*) from table2

DO WHILE (@CurrCount < @TopCount)
 BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO table3 (columns)
  SELECT columns from table2 LIMIT 50
  DELETE table2 LIMIT 50
  SET @CurrCount = @CurrCount + 50
 END;
END WHILE;
```

This is pretty silly, imho, but I still do not understand your goal.