# MySQL - While Exists from a snippet throws error

Tags: mysql, sql

I was reading through this page https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql (great article on managing hierarchical data in SQL) and following along in MySQL and was trying to run this SQL snippet.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Depth Is Null) 
UPDATE T SET T.depth = P.Depth + 1, 
T.Lineage = P.Lineage + Ltrim(Str(T.ParentNode,6,0)) + '/' 
FROM Tree AS T 
INNER JOIN Tree AS P ON (T.ParentNode=P.Node) 
WHERE P.Depth>=0 
AND P.Lineage Is Not Null 
AND T.Depth Is Null
```

Except I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around:
>   'WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Depth Is Null ) UPDATE' at
>   line 1

I've tried adding in `BEGIN`, `END`, `END WHILE` etc from suggestions in [While exists in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640205/while-exists-in-mysql) but still not working.

You can try and run the above snippet in an SQL validator (https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ is a good free online one) and see the error.

I'm looking for suggestions on why the above snippet doesn't work from the blog / what can be changed so the same result is achieved.

**Update - Adding in more data**

Thanks @danblack for the suggestion to add more data to make it a verifiable example.

**My current table**

```
Node    ParentNode  EmployeeID  Depth   Lineage
100     NULL        1001        0       /
101     100         1002        NULL    NULL
102     101         1003        NULL    NULL
103     102         1004        NULL    NULL
104     102         1005        NULL    NULL
105     102         1006        NULL    NULL
```

**What it should look like after the snippet is run**

```
Node    ParentNode  EmployeeID  Depth   Lineage
100     NULL        1001        0       /
101     100         1002        1       /100/
102     101         1003        2       /100/101/
103     102         1004        3       /100/101/102/
104     102         1005        3       /100/101/102/
105     102         1006        3       /100/101/102/
```

@danblack pointed out that the snippet is Microsoft SQL, not MySQL and should use a recursive CTE to do this. This is my attempt but I still can't figure it out.

```
;WITH user_count
AS
(
SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Depth Is Null AS null_users
UNION ALL
WHILE EXISTS () 
UPDATE T SET T.depth = P.Depth + 1, 
T.Lineage = P.Lineage + Ltrim(Str(T.ParentNode,6,0)) + '/' 
FROM Tree AS T 
INNER JOIN Tree AS P ON (T.ParentNode=P.Node) 
WHERE P.Depth>=0 
AND P.Lineage Is Not Null 
AND T.Depth Is Null
)
```

Comment: The sqlteam amd eversql is Microsoft SQL, not MySQL which is why there is syntax that MySQL doesn't recognise. What you ask is possible with recursive CTEs in MySQL-8.0 and MariaDB-10.2+ if you have one of these versions.

Comment: Can you show some table structure, sample data and what you expect the output to look like? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: I've updated the question @danblack to be more verifiable and shown my work so far in making it a recursive CTE but am stuck on how to do it as the examples I've found haven't dealt with an `UPDATE` statement in the CTE, only `SELECT.

Comment: What is the error or behavior with the new syntax?

Comment: The SQL-99 CTE syntax is not like the the Microsoft SQL syntax. The `WHILE EXISTS` is fairly redundant as the finishing of the recursion occurs when the following part of the query (SELECT only in MySQL), returning 0 rows is always the recursion end criteria. Any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (in [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)) appears at the tail of the CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In MySQL-8.0:**

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.13    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tree (
>   `Node` VARCHAR(3),
>   `ParentNode` VARCHAR(3),
>   `EmployeeID` INTEGER,
>   `Depth` INTEGER,
>   `Lineage` VARCHAR(16)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tree
>   (`Node`, `ParentNode`, `EmployeeID`, `Depth`, `Lineage`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', NULL, '1001', 0, '/'),
>   ('101', '100', '1002', NULL, NULL),
>   ('102', '101', '1003', NULL, NULL),
>   ('103', '102', '1004', NULL, NULL),
>   ('104', '102', '1005', NULL, NULL),
>   ('105', '102', '1006', NULL, NULL);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE prev AS (
> SELECT * FROM tree WHERE ParentNode IS NULL
> UNION
> SELECT t.Node,t.ParentNode,t.EmployeeID,p.Depth + 1 as Depth, CONCAT(p.Lineage, t.ParentNode, '/')
> FROM tree t
> JOIN prev p ON t.ParentNode = p.Node
> )
> SELECT * FROM prev;
> ```
>
> ```
> Node | ParentNode | EmployeeID | Depth | Lineage      
> :--- | :--------- | ---------: | ----: | :------------
> 100  | null       |       1001 |     0 | /            
> 101  | 100        |       1002 |     1 | /100/        
> 102  | 101        |       1003 |     2 | /100/101/    
> 103  | 102        |       1004 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 104  | 102        |       1005 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 105  | 102        |       1006 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE prev AS (
> SELECT * FROM tree WHERE ParentNode IS NULL
> UNION
> SELECT t.Node,t.ParentNode,t.EmployeeID,p.Depth + 1 as Depth, CONCAT(p.Lineage, t.ParentNode, '/')
> FROM prev p
> JOIN tree t ON t.ParentNode = p.Node
> )
> UPDATE tree t, prev p
> SET t.Depth=p.Depth, t.Lineage=p.Lineage
> WHERE t.Node=p.Node;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tree
> ```
>
> ```
> Node | ParentNode | EmployeeID | Depth | Lineage      
> :--- | :--------- | ---------: | ----: | :------------
> 100  | null       |       1001 |     0 | /            
> 101  | 100        |       1002 |     1 | /100/        
> 102  | 101        |       1003 |     2 | /100/101/    
> 103  | 102        |       1004 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 104  | 102        |       1005 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 105  | 102        |       1006 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> ```

*[mysql8.0 db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21ef8d80cd97de45f84b85a9613f6dc4)*

**MariaDB does [not yet supported UPDATE in CTEs](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18511)**

However it can be performed with a temporary table like:

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newtree AS
> WITH RECURSIVE prev AS (
> SELECT * FROM tree WHERE ParentNode IS NULL
> UNION
> SELECT t.Node,t.ParentNode,t.EmployeeID,p.Depth + 1 as Depth, CONCAT(p.Lineage, t.ParentNode, '/')
> FROM tree t JOIN prev p ON t.ParentNode = p.Node
> )
> SELECT Node,Depth,Lineage FROM prev;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE tree t, newtree p SET t.Depth=p.Depth, t.Lineage=p.Lineage WHERE t.Node=p.Node;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from tree
> ```
>
> ```
> Node | ParentNode | EmployeeID | Depth | Lineage      
> :--- | :--------- | ---------: | ----: | :------------
> 100  | null       |       1001 |     0 | /            
> 101  | 100        |       1002 |     1 | /100/        
> 102  | 101        |       1003 |     2 | /100/101/    
> 103  | 102        |       1004 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 104  | 102        |       1005 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> 105  | 102        |       1006 |     3 | /100/101/102/
> ```

*[MariaDB-10.3 db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=90d296692cf751d365cdbe31dc089862)*

Comment: Oh my gosh this is truly above and beyond, thank you so much for providing the in-depth examples and the fiddle to try it out myself. I hope others find this answer as it is exactly what I was looking for! Have an awesome day and thank you again for helping me understanding how to do something new in MySQL! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good questions of interest help. The [explanation of CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) should reaffirm the anchor and recursive parts of the CTE here.